# Duvida de como mostrar o resultado usando JOptionPane

Tags: java, joptionpane

Estou querendo fazer um programa para buscar parte de uma string em um vetor.
Só que queria fazer e mostrar em uma janela. Do jeito que eu fiz deu certo, mas quando eu pesquiso por "caderno", gera uma janela com um resultado e depois que eu clico em "OK" gera outra janela com o segundo resultado. Como faço pra gerar somente uma janela com todos os resultado ao mesmo tempo?

```
public class Loja0001 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] produto = new String[6];

        produto[0] = "cola = 5,00";
        produto[1] = "caneta = 1,00";
        produto[2] = "borracha = 0,50";
        produto[3] = "lapis = 0,50";
        produto[4] = "caderno 10 materias = 10,00";
        produto[5] = "caderno 20 materias 15,00";

        String filtro = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "informe o produto:");

        for (String stringAtual : produto) {
            if (stringAtual.contains(filtro)) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, stringAtual);
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma alternativa é armazenar o resultado em uma variavel e posteriormente utilizar

```
public class Loja0001 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] produto = new String[6];
        produto[0] = "cola = 5,00";
        produto[1] = "caneta = 1,00";
        produto[2] = "borracha = 0,50";
        produto[3] = "lapis = 0,50";
        produto[4] = "caderno 10 materias = 10,00";
        produto[5] = "caderno 20 materias 15,00";

        String filtro = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "informe o produto:");
        String msg = "";
        for(String stringAtual : produto) {
            if (stringAtual.contains(filtro)) {
                msg += stringAtual + "\n";
            }
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, msg);
    }
}
```